# running exec bundle cucumber closes terminal immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

i was using the command

```
`exec bundle cucumber features/filter_movie_list.feature --guess`
```

on ubuntu running on virtual box and it was working fine but today running the same command closes the terminal immediately.

Answer (score 3):

It's [`bundle exec`](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html) not `exec bundle`. The latter is running the [`exec` bash command](http://ss64.com/bash/exec.html), which replaces the shell with the given process, causing the terminal to close after it completes.

Answer (score 2):

bundle exec cucumber features/filter_movie_list.feature --guess

It is not exec bundle